# Clean way to filter an array of dictionaries by unique dictionary values

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

Say I have an object:

```
struct Foo {
    let id: Int
    let bar: Int
}
```

Now I have 5 of these objects in an array:

```
let foo1 = Foo(id: 1, bar: 1)
let foo2 = Foo(id: 2, bar: 1)
let foo3 = Foo(id: 3, bar: 2)
let foo4 = Foo(id: 4, bar: 3)
let foo5 = Foo(id: 5, bar: 3)

let fooArray = [foo1, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5]
```

What would be a clean way of filtering `foo` objects that have unique `bar` values?

```
// Desired output
let filteredArray = [foo1, foo3, foo4]
```

Assume there's anywhere from a few hundred to a few thousand objects to iterate upon.

Comment: How about using a filter like this:

    `fooArray.filter {($0.bar.contains(searchBar))}`

Comment: The title and body of your question seem to differ – do you have an array of dictionaries or an array of structs?

Comment: I have an array of structs, although the answer to this question doesn't apply specifically to struct types. Feel free to edit to the title to something more semantically appropriate if you feel it's confusing, I don't feel confident coming up with a better title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach is to use a `Set` which keeps track of which
`bar` values have already been seen:

```
var seenBarValues = Set<Int>()
let filteredArray = fooArray.filter { foo in
    if seenBarValues.contains(foo.bar) {
        // We already had a `Foo` with this `bar` value: skip.
        return false 
    } else {
        // First `Foo` with this `bar` value: remember and include.
        seenBarValues.insert(foo.bar)
        return true
    }
}
```

As @Hamish correctly pointed out, this can be shortened to

```
var seenBarValues = Set<Int>()
let filteredArray = fooArray.filter { 
    seenBarValues.insert($0.bar).inserted
}
```

using the fact that

```
public mutating func insert(_ newMember: Element) -> (inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Element)
```

returns a tuple whose first member indicates if an element equal
to the newly inserted one was already present in the set.

Comment: Or you could just say `fooArray.filter { seenBarValues.insert($0.bar).inserted }` :)

Comment: These are great solutions. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of the accepted answer. Having the set outside the closure that uses it doesn't seem appropriate. I would rather keep everything contained. There's a CS term that applies but I don't remember what it is...

I would rather see this:

```
let uniquedBars = fooArray
    .reduce(into: (result: [Foo](), set: Set<Int>())) { partial, next in
        if partial.set.insert(next.bar).inserted {
            partial.result.append(next)
        }
    }
    .result
```