# Filtering unique names of an array with massive amount of objects

Tags: ios, swift, performance

I'm currently fetching a lot of objects that contains both names and coordinates of streets. The returned array has around 22.000 objects and the resulting array we want has around 4000, the rest are duplicates. The problem with this kind of data is that the fetched objects can have the same name but different coordinates, and i'm only interested by getting objects based on unique names. If there are more than one object with the same name, i'll only want to keep the first object.

So far i've been trying to loop through the streets by comparing the names. I'd rather use `filter` or some other more performance efficient solution.

#### My struct

```
struct StreetName {
    var name: String
    var polyLine: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

#### My code so far

```
DataManager.shared.getStreetNames { (streets) in  
    var namesArray: [StreetName] = []
    for streetName in streets {
        let name = streetName.name
        if namesArray.count == 0 {
            namesArray.append(streetName)
        } else if namesArray.contains(where: {$0.name == name }) { 
             /* Dont add */ 
        } else {
             namesArray.append(streetName)
        }
    }

    self.streetNames = namesArray.sorted(by: {$0.name < $1.name})
    self.filteredStreetNames = self.streetNames
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        self.streetTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This code block works, but runs in around 30 seconds on an iPhone X. Which is way too slow. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest this question is reopened, the proposed duplicate addresses removing duplicates, but doesn't address the efficiency issue.

Comment: Why did you remove the `sort` portion of your code?

Comment: Reverted the edit

Comment: Perhaps, use a query that will return a sorted array of streets straight from your database. Removing the duplicates is then easy with a forward iterator or use a tailored `reduce` function.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use another query, so this all I have @CouchDeveloper

Comment: What about putting all street names into a `Set` ?

Comment: I was thinking about using `Set`, but since all coordinates are unique in all objects I just want to compare the names. @MartinR

Comment: This is what i meant: [Clean way to filter an array of dictionaries by unique dictionary values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42542035/1187415)

Comment: @MartinR You sir, solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MartinR solved this by using `Sets`.

#### My new updated struct

```
struct StreetName: Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: StreetName, rhs: StreetName) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return name.hashValue
    }

    var name: String
    var polyLine: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

#### My new updated code

```
DataManager.shared.getStreetNames { (returnedNamesSet) in
    var namesArray: [StreetName] = Array(returnedNamesSet)

    self.streetNames = namesArray.sorted(by: {$0.name < $1.name})
    self.filteredStreetNames = self.streetNames
    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        self.streetTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

### Results:

The process time went from 30 seconds to 0.4 seconds by using `Set`

Comment: Your implementation of `==` is wrong: Different strings can have identical hash values.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to solve this? So far i'm having no problem with this, but you're correct about that @MartinR

Comment: If equality is based only on the street *names* then just `return lhs.name == rhs.name`

Comment: Btw, making type itself hashable is not exactly what I suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42542237/1187415, but to keep all names seen so far in a `Set<String>`.

Comment: Thanks it's working perfectly, I'll edit the answer! Really, thanks @MartinR

Comment: I can add that I also took some help from a friend, I combined your knowledge together

Answer (score 2):

I think if you profile this, you'll find that the `sort` is taking the most time. I can't find an official note, but there's a good chance that the underlying implementation is **quick sort**, which has it's worst complexity when the array is already sorted (or the array is sorted in reverse order).

The average case complexity for quick sort is O(n log n), but in the worst case it's O(n<sup>2</sup>).

I think you should implement insertion sort instead, or, more accurately, always insert the new elements into an already sorted position. This should reduce your complexity to O(n) for the entire function.

**Pseudocode:**

- Fetch street names
- For each street name

  - find the position in the existing array where the street name would go (I suggest binary search since the array is already sorted)
  - if the street name already exists, skip
  - if the name doesn't exist, insert it.

The result should be a sorted array of unique street names requiring each name to only be read and inserted once.

Comment: If the array is already "somewhat"  sorted which is not optimal for quick sort, how about `shuffle` then `quick sort` then `reduce`?

Comment: I also like the idea of this, but have a hard time trying to figure out how to make this pseudo code into code. Any pointers?

Comment: In the suggested [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array) the [answer of mxcl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738817/removing-duplicate-elements-from-an-array/46354989#46354989) provides the most efficient way to remove duplicates. By comparison the time to sort the array is negligible.

Comment: Swift uses *introsort* (a variant of quick sort), compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/27677026/1187415. Whether an already sorted array is the worst case or not depends on the choice of the pivot element. [Apparently](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sort.swift.gyb#L191) Swift uses the middle value from the first, middle, last element.

Comment: @vadian - Doesn't this compare equal objects? The objects in this case is unique, but some values might be same...

Comment: @vadian If the original array is sorted (or can be sorted and used as the input) and if the order of the result is not relevant, there seems to be a better algorithm than the proposed solution from mxcl.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this:

```
// Given an array of elements (here just Ints):
let array = (0..<1000).map { _ in Int(arc4random_uniform(100)) }

// Sort it:
let sorted = array.sorted()

// Define an empty result (array of elements) which is a variable 
// and which gets modified in the subsequent reduce function:
var unique: [Int] = []

// A tailored reduce which depends on a sorted array and appends 
// to the result IFF that element is not the last in result:
let result = sorted.reduce(into: unique) { (result, element) in
    if let last = result.last, last == element {
    } else {
        result.append(element)
    }
}
```

Finally, print the result:

```
print(array)
```

Example output on the console:
`console
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]`